# Create a object array using string for the name then referencing array with string

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, sharepoint

Two issues I'm struggling with:

1. Creating new arrays using strings from another array.
2. Referencing an array name with string/variable.

For context, I'm trying to put an employee team list in object array, but there are too many employees for the 100 maximum array. So my strategy is to create new arrays using team managers' names. These lists change frequently (not the TM's so much) but I'd like to be hands off the maintenance part.

For example, the first array is for the Team Managers' Active Directory.
I can get this with an ajax get.

```
var arr_TMs = [jsmith, kjohnson, smichaels]
```

Because the TM's can change, I want to create new arrays for each TM using the arr_TMs as the names for array itself

```
$.each( arr_TMs, function(i,v) {
    //here is issue #1
    var arr_ + v = []
})
```

The results would be something like:

arr_jsmith
arr_kjohnson
arr_smichaels

I want to use these new arrays to push the agents' objects into.
I have the TM's AD in an Employee Master List that the agent reports to.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "mysite.ca/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Employee Master List')/items?$filter=JobTitle eq 'Agent'&$select=Name,Skill,TeamManager_AD",
     type: "GET",
     async: false,
     headers: {"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"},
     success: function(data) {
          //here is #2 something like this:
          "arr_" + data.TeamManager_AD = data.d.results
     },
     error: function(err) {console.log(err)}
});
```

After that syntax I hope to get these arrays that I can reference later:

```
arr_jsmith [
   {Name: "James, Jesse", Skill: "Outlaw", TeamManagerAD: "jsmith"}
   {Name: "Mortenson, Norma", Skill: "Actress", TeamManagerAD: "jsmith"}
   {Name: "Dean, James", Skill: "Motorcycle", TeamManagerAD: "jsmith"}
]

//And so on....
arr_kjohnson [
   {Name: "Mortenson, Norma", Skill: "Actress", TeamManagerAD: "kjohnson"}
   {Name: "Mortenson, Norma", Skill: "Actress", TeamManagerAD: "kjohnson"}
]

arr_smichaels [
   {Name: "Mortenson, Norma", Skill: "Actress", TeamManagerAD: "smichaels"}
]
```

But issue #2 comes up again if I want to reference the array name dynamically, I think it's something like this:

```
If ($('#myinput').Value === jsmith) {
     var tmad = $('#myinput').Value

     //this I can't get to work:
     $.each(window["arr_" + tmad], function(i, v) {
          var empName = window['arr_' + tmad].Name
          var empSkill = window['arr_' + tmad].Skill
          console.log(empName + ' - ' + empSkill)
     });

}
```

Where the output would be:

```
"James, Jesse - Outlaw"
"Mortenson, Norma - Actress"
"Dean, James - Motorcycle"
```

Unless of course, you know of a much more simple expression of this goal.

Appreciate your insight on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the `window[]` and it's working by using the `new Array()` to create a new array.
First I changed my arr_TMs to include the TM name:

```
arr_TMs(
   {"name":"Smith, John", "ActiveDirectory":"jsmith"}
   {"name":"Johnson, Kate", "ActiveDirectory":"kjohnson"}
   {"name":"Michaels, Sean", "ActiveDirectory":"smichaels"}
)
```

Then I just used the `$.each` to create the arrays "dynamically":

```
var ad = '' //I declared this outside the loop so I can use it in the ajax later
$.each( arr_TMs, function(i,v) {
   ad = v.ActiveDirectory
   window["arr_" + ad] = new Array()
})
```

Now in the $.ajax I can do the same thing

```
$.ajax({
    //minor change to my filter so that it only pulls for that TM
    //I added a filter with the and $filter=TeamManager eq 'ad' and JobTitle eq 'Agent'

    url: "mysite.ca/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Employee Master List')/items?$filter=TeamManger eq '" + ad + "' and JobTitle eq 'Agent'&$select=Name,Skill,TeamManager_AD",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: {"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data) {
         //#2 here
         window["arr_" + ad] = data.d.results
 },
 error: function(err) {console.log(err)}
});
```

Now I can just reference using the same `window["arr_" + ad]` to pull from any of the arrays.

```
var lookup = $("#myinput").value //value = jsmith
//as long as the value matches the Active Directory ex: jsmith `arr_jsmith`
console.log( window["arr_" + lookup] )
```